# Use identity server 3 to exchange a facebook token for my application token

Tags: identityserver3

I'm investigating how to use id server to provide auth services for a native mobile app that will talk to a Web API that we are developing. I started off with the flow as described in the MVC walkthrough - so the user is redirected by ID Server to FB (with acr_value/idp) and then redirected back after sign-in, where I can do the claims transformation and issue a token for our application.

The developers of the native client have concerns about this though, and would rather use the FB sdk to log the user in to FB, instead of having id server issue the token after redirections. The following issue on the previous version of ID server explains this well:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer2/issues/503

How would I go about doing this with id server 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for a custom grant.

1) first do native FB login

2) send FB token to IdentityServer token endpoint using custom grant

3) write a custom grant validator that validates the FB token

4) return JWT token for your APIs

Documentation:
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customGrantTypes.html